# Get method to Object in Object Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have Data Model project in Angular 2. I have only three classes.

```
class Menu {
  name: string;
  categories: { [name: string]: Category };
}

class Category {
  name: string;
  dishes: { [name: string]: Dish };
}

class Dish {
  name: string;
}
```

In every class I have two methods created.

`getName(){ return this.name }` // in all classes

and

`getCategory() { return this.categories }` // in case of Menu class

`getDishes() { return this.dishes }` // in case of Category class

In my home.ts Component, I have the Data request (http request) from the backend, and I put all the data in those classes. This is working OK.

```
  getMenus() {
    this.globals.getMenus().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.menus = {};
        Object.keys(data).forEach(name => {
          this.menus[name] = new Menu(data[name]);
        });

        console.log(this.menus);
      },
      err => { console.log(err) }
    );
  }
```

console.log(this.menus) is working OK and prints all the data model correctly.

Now, my question is:

How can I use the get methods to make a list in my home.html with all the data, like:

> - Menu 1
> - "name of menu"
> - Category 1
> - "name of category"
>
>   - Dish 1
>
>     - "name of dish 1"
> - Category 2
> - "name of category 2"
>
>   - Dish 1
>
>     - "name of dish 1"
> - Menu 2
> - "name of menu 2
>
>   - Category 1
>   - ... etc

That's the Json Server Response:

```js
{
  "menu_1": {
    "name": "Menú de día",
    "cat_1": {
      "name": "Entrantes",
      "dish_1": {
        "Name": "Ensalada Romana"
      },
      "dish_2": {
        "Name": "Sopa de galets"
      }
    },
    "cat_2": {
      "name": "Segundos",
      "dish_1": {
        "Name": "Calamares a la romana"
      },
      "dish_2": {
        "Name": "Tortilla de patatas"
      }
    }
  },
  "menu_2": {
    "name": "Menú Principal",
    "cat_1": {
      "name": "Primer Plato",
      "dish_1": {
        "Name": "Ensalada Romana"
      },
      "dish_2": {
        "Name": "Sopa de galets"
      }
    },
    "cat_2": {
      "name": "Segundo Plato",
      "dish_1": {
        "Name": "Calamares a la romana"
      },
      "dish_2": {
        "Name": "Tortilla de patatas"
      }
    },
    "cat_3": {
      "name": "Postres",
      "dish_1": {
        "Name": "Crema Catalana"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array in you class, to make it more statically typed.

```
class Menu {
  name: string;
  categories: Array<Category>; // initialize it as applicable
}
class Category {
  name: string;
  dishes: Array<Dish>;// initialize it as applicable
}
class Dish {
  name: string;
}
```

**Component**

You can try fill `this.menus` which will also be strongly typed `Array<Menu>`
// make sure the code is writen to compile.

```
getMenus() {
    this.globals.getMenus().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.menus = new Array<Menu>();
        Object.keys(data).forEach(name => {
          //Initialize and push items as per data structure. 
          this.menus.push(new Menu(data[name]));
        });

        console.log(this.menus);
      },
      err => { console.log(err) }
    );
  }
```

**template**
Arrange the following as a combination of Un-ordered and ordered list.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let menu of menus">
        {{ menu.name }}
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let category of menu.categories">
                {{ category.name }}
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let dish of category.dishes">
                        {{ dish.name }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Javier If you feel this should be the answer , accept it so that others can use, if not and you did something better post here, this make a good community contribution :)

Comment: Done @Ankesh ;)

Answer (score 0):

Angular's `*ngFor` will only work with iterable objects, not with maps.

Could look like this, using a `Pipe` to convert your maps into arrays:

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let m of menus | mapToArray">
        {{ m.name }}
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let c of m.categories | mapToArray">
                {{ c.name }}
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let d of c.dishes | mapToArray">
                        {{ d.name }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the `Pipe`:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'mapToArray'
})
export class MapToArrayPipe {
  public transform(map: any): any[] {
    if (!map) return [];
    return Object.keys(map).map(k => map[k]);
  }
}
```

live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/HzwRftZXWnDlCZWJwL0d?p=preview

Comment: That looks good, but throws me an error:
Error in ./HomePage class HomePage - caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: I see, your `menus` isnt an array, its an object.. Best way would be to change it to an array of menus instead of a map of menus. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I do that, what is the sense to make a Data Model with data stored in classes in Angular 2? :( And even if I do this, It will throws me an error too because Menus have Objects type Category inside.

Comment: please add a complete JSON-respone to your question. I will create a plunker then! :)

Comment: You can make data-models, for sure! thats great. but `*ngFor` will only work with iterable objects. Otherwise you could use a `Pipe` to convert your map into an array. I will provide a plunker if you could add your json server response. :)

Comment: Thanks mxii, I edited my post with my json server response ;)

Comment: Hi mxii, thanks! I save your answer because looks good, but other user solved my question, thanks for your attention, I give to you my vote. :)